# SyncFusion Treeview Event in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syncfusion

How i can use events with angularjs? i read the documentation but they dont mention anything about this only databinding and i dont want to use javascript or jquery to use this events.

```
<div id="treeView" ej-treeview e-fields-datasource="vm.list" e-fields-id="id" e-fields-parentid="pid" e-fields-text="name" e-fields-haschild="hasChild" e-fields-expanded="expanded" />
```

I try the attributes:

- e-fields-options
- e-field-nodeSelect
- e-field-model

and nothing work.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

PD: Sorry for my english :(

Answer (score 0):

You mean the clientside events, then you have to provide the as follows.

```
<div id="treeView" ej-treeview e-fields-datasource="vm.list"  e-expanded="expanded" e-nodeselect="selected" />
```

> The Syncfusion angular control properties are same as the javascript controls we have to provide the properties prefixed with 'e-' thats all its simple..:)